# How do you get ESLint to work for jsx in VS2017?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-2017, eslint

I've noticed that VS-2017 has ESLint built in. It works great for my javascript files. Is there a way to get it to work for jsx files? Specifically react-jsx if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good bit of searching I found that jsx support works best when the file is a .js instead of .jsx. Changed the extension and ESLint immediately began complaining :)